# I am wondering how can i rate limit my php api so a ip or client cant use it for 5 minutes

Tags: php

So, i have a super basic php api for my website and i need it to be rate limited.
Like a cooldown so the ip cant access the api for 5 minutes.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Store the IP in a database with the _time of access_ and then compare that to _now_ when they try again?

Comment: I am super new to api and stuff and idk nothing about databases

Comment: What's your API for? Do you have a DB in use or ability to have one on your server? (`mysql` would be probably the most common?)

Comment: So it gets a random string from a text file and displays it

Comment: This is what it looks like a bit of it
 `<?php
2
    $type = $_GET['type'];
3
​
4
    if (empty($type)) {
5
        die('Please include all required url parameters.');
6
    }
7
​
8
    if ($type === 'Minecraft') {
9
        $db = '../accounts/minecraft.txt';
$account = file($db, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  echo $account[array_rand($account)];`

Comment: How many hits per second are you expecting?

Comment: hmm idk like 1 per client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could do it, in order of preference....

1. Use a database; have a table which logs the `ip` and `timestamp` then lookup the `ip` on every request and check the time of the last request is more than **5** minutes ago
2. Use a file to store the request `ip` and `timestamp` in something like `CSV` or `JSON` format. Then loop over the file with each request...

Seeing as you don't say anything about access to a database, here is a version for a `JSON` formatted file:

*Note: you need to update the `$filePath` variable*

```
$ip           = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$filePath     = "./path/to/file.json";    // Set this to a file on your server
$ipList       = json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath), true);
$throttleTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-5 minutes");

$allowAccess  = true;

foreach ($ipList as $key => $row) {

    // Check if the IP has accessed the site in the last 5 minutes
    if ($row["ip"] === $ip && $row["timestamp"] > $throttleTime)) {
        $allowAccess = false;
    }

    // Remove the entry if over 5 minutes old; not restricted to IP
    //   >> Garbage colection
    if ($row["timestamp"] < $throttleTime) {
        unset($ipList[$key]);
    }
}

$ipList[] = [
    "ip"        => $ip,
    "timestamp" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
];

// Update the 
file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode(array_values($ipList)));

// Check to see if the user is allowed access; exit with error message if not.
if (!$allowAccess) {
    echo "Error, you've accessed this site too many times. Try again in 5 minutes.";
    exit;
}

// The user is allowed... Do something....
echo "We're in!";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help

Comment: @BL4CK98 No worries, just remember that this won't scale well if you end up with thousands and thousands of hits per second!

Comment: Noted I hope you have a good day sir you saved my day =)